# Searching for articles in Wikipedia XML Dump based on its Categories

Tags: python, wikipedia, gensim

I would like to find or to design a parser that can find the wikipedia XML Dump but I am unable to find any nor do I have any idea on how to do it.

I have tried using wikiextractor but unfortunately it does not extract articles based on the user defined categories but instead it extract articles that contain the keyword.

For example in the xml file that I have downloaded, the wikipedia article "Anarchism".This article can be found in the following categories:

```
[[Category:Anarchism| ]]
[[Category:Political culture]]
[[Category:Political ideologies]]
[[Category:Social theories]]
[[Category:Anti-fascism]]
[[Category:Anti-capitalism]]
[[Category:Far-left politics]]
```

For example part of the xml for Anarchism:

```
 <page>
    <title>Anarchism</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>12</id>
    <revision>
      <id>716551092</id>
      <parentid>714146352</parentid>
      <timestamp>2016-04-22T10:19:33Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <ip>85.193.216.88</ip>
      </contributor>
      <comment>a better word;  use [[plain English]] -&gt; [[WP:MOS]]</comment>
      <model>wikitext</model>
      <format>text/x-wiki</format>
      <text xml:space="preserve">{{Redirect2|Anarchist|Anarchists|the fictional character|Anarchist (comics)|other uses|Anarchists (disambiguation)}}
{{pp-move-indef}}
{{Use British English|date=January 2014}}
{{Anarchism sidebar}}
'''Anarchism''' is a [[political philosophy]] that advocates [[self-governance|self-governed]] societies based on voluntary institutions. These are often described as [[stateless society|stateless societies]],&lt;ref&gt;&quot;ANARCHISM, a social philosophy that rejects authoritarian government and maintains that voluntary institutions are best suited to express man's natural social tendencies.&quot; George Woodcock. &quot;Anarchism&quot; at The Encyclopedia of Philosophy&lt;/ref&gt;&lt;ref&gt;&quot;In a society developed on these lines, the voluntary associations which already now begin to cover all the fields of human activity would take a still greater extension so as to substitute themselves for the state in all its functions.&quot; [http://www.theanarchistlibrary.org/HTML/Petr_Kropotkin___Anarchism__from_the_Encyclopaedia_Britannica.html Peter Kropotkin. &quot;Anarchism&quot; from the Encyclopædia Britannica]&lt;/ref&gt;&lt;ref&gt;&quot;Anarchism.&quot; The Shorter Routledge Encyclopedia of Philosophy. 2005. p. 14 &quot;Anarchism is the view that a society without the state, or government, is both possible and desirable.&quot;&lt;/ref&gt;&lt;ref&gt;Sheehan, Sean. Anarchism, London: Reaktion Books Ltd., 2004. p. 85&lt;/ref&gt; although several authors have defined them more specifically as institutions based on non-[[Hierarchy|hierarchical]] [[Free association (communism and anarchism)|free associations]].&lt;ref&gt;&quot;as many anarchists have stressed, it is not government as such that they find objectionable, but the hierarchical forms of government associated with the nation state.&quot; Judith Suissa. ''Anarchism and Education: a Philosophical Perspective''. Routledge. New York. 2006. p. 7&lt;/ref&gt;&lt;ref name=&quot;iaf-ifa.org&quot;/&gt;&lt;ref&gt;&quot;That is why Anarchy, when it works to destroy authority in all its aspects, when it demands the abrogation of laws and the abolition of the mechanism that serves to impose them, when it refuses all hierarchical organisation and preaches free agreement — at the same time strives to maintain and enlarge the precious kernel of social customs without which no human or animal society can exist.&quot; [[Peter Kropotkin]]. [http://www.theanarchistlibrary.org/HTML/Petr_Kropotkin__Anarchism__its_philosophy_and_ideal.html Anarchism: its philosophy and ideal]&lt;/ref&gt;&lt;ref&gt;&quot;anarchists are opposed to irrational (e.g., illegitimate) authority, in other words, hierarchy — hierarchy being the institutionalisation of authority within a society.&quot; [http://www.theanarchistlibrary.org/HTML/The_Anarchist_FAQ_Editorial_Collective__An_Anarchist_FAQ__03_17_.html#toc2 &quot;B.1 Why are anarchists against authority and hierarchy?&quot;] in [[An Anarchist FAQ]]&lt;/ref&gt; Anarchism considers the [[state (polity)|state]] to be undesirable, unnecessary, and harmful.&lt;ref name=&quot;definition&quot;&gt;
```

I would like to search the Wikipedia XML dump for all articles that is contained in a particular category like for example, `[[Category:Anti-fascism]]` and to generate the XML file. I will then clean the XML file so that I can train it using gensim word2vec model.

Please advice me on how to do it, I have only basic programming experience and I need to do this in Python.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and include a short extract of the XML?

Comment: I still see no XML in your question.

Comment: Hi , i have edited it. Thanks

Comment: Pages can end up in categories by means of templates, possibly in multiple transclusions, meaning that it will be tricky for you to determine the category from looking at the wiki text only. You might want to have a look at the MediaWiki API, and the many Python libraries that allow you to fetch e.g. all pages from a given category: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#Python

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Which script is better in the list that you  provided?